# "autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" only on iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I'm getting hundreds of this message in the console:

```
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5d86f30 of class NSIndexPath autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

In addition to many more messages about classes other than NSIndexPath.

I'm aware this means that objects are autoreleased with no autorelease pool to add them too, but why is this happening on iOS 4.3 only and not iOS 5.0/.1

Also how come there's no autorelease pool to add autoreleased objects too if the return value of main() is wrapped in NSAutoreleasePool object?

Comment: Are you running code on a thread that's not the main one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but the autoreleasepool in the main() works for the UIThread (in 4.3 at least) when you open another thread you should put a new autoreleasepool around it (only if you use autoreleases).

Comment: I wasn't aware that the autorelease pool in main() works only for the UIThread. Thanks a lot. I'm just wondering how it never showed up on 5.0

Comment: I think that 5.0 might have fixed that problem and the autorelease pool might work for all subthreads of the uithread. Just a speculation tho.